# When is skbuf memory allocated with PF_MEMALLOC

Tags: linux-kernel

There are multiple checks in the Linux kernel networking code whether a skb has pfmemalloc flag set, e.g. here:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.8/source/net/core/dev.c#L5315

Under what circumstances is the PF_MEMALLOC flag set on skbs and why?